# Wakanda add collection

Tags: javascript, wakanda

I have install [wakanda](http://www.wakanda.org/) and testing in my computer.

Then I testing to create 2 tables named `table1` and `table2` with structure like this:

> table1: ID, Name, table2Collection
>   table2: ID, Table1, Name

I want to create trigger that when `table1` is saved, a new row is also inserted in to `table2` and to create relation between `table1` and `table2`.

I try to create event on table1 `On Save` like this:

```
var newTable2 = new ds.table2;
newTable2.Name = this.Name;
newTable2.save();
```

But this code not create relation between table1 and table2.
Can some body help me?

Answer (score 1):

Wakanda is an object database. We don't talk about Tables but about DataClasses.

Here two level of answers for your question:

1. **Triggers**: Wakanda as "events" to which you can assign JavaScript functions and one of them is "save". You can fix it via [the event tab in the Datastore Model Designer](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html/Wakanda-Studio-Reference-Guide/Datastore-Model-Designer/Datastore-Classes.300-305138.en.html#664427), or directly in JavaScript via [the Model API](http://doc.wakanda.org/Model/DatastoreClass-Events.201-1029688.en.html) if using free form edition. Events like "on save" exist [at the Dataclass and the attribute levels](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda-Server-Side-Concepts/Class-Events-and-Attribute-Events.200-715336.en.html)
2. **Relations**: Wakanda as "relation attributes". In your example, you are copying a string value. You should better have an entity relation attribute and have code like

```
    var newDataClass2 = new DataClass2();
    newDataClass2.dataClass1 = this;
    newDataClass2.save();
```

your Name attribute would be accessible through newDataClass2.dataClass1.Name
or could be available through newDataClass2.dataClass1Name if you add an alias attribute

Comment: Hallo Alexandre, thanks for your answer.I thinks trigger on Save triggered before save so that code cannot work if dataClass1 is new.